# Cutting sound for a second in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudiosession

I am able to play sound in background using MPMoviePlayerController.But the problem is whenever i go to the background and foreground state there is a cut of sound or repetition of words in video for 1 or 2 second.

This is my code:

```
- (void)playVideo:(id)sender {
    if (_urlToLoad) 
    {
       mp1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:_urlToLoad];
       self.mc3=mp1;
       mp1.view.frame = self.view.bounds; //Set the size
      [self.view addSubview:mp1.view]; //Show the view
      [mp1 play];
      AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
      NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
     if (![session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                  withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                        error:&setCategoryError])
     {
        // handle error
     }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

   }
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification*)note 
{
    double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
               {

                   [mp1 play];
         });
}
```

Please tell me if i am wrong.

Comment: why can't you [mp1 play]; directly..with any delay..at applicationDidEnterBackground..

Comment: No i tried that also but its not working.